# Calculating Year-Over-Year values with missing years

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a data set where there are a bunch of regions and each region has a number of completed projects, incomplete projects, and the overall inventory for each specific region on a yearly basis.

```
Region       Year    Completions    Incomplete    Inventory
New York     1999    100            200           1500
New York     2000    150            100           1650
New York     2001    125            100           1775
                           ....
Oregon       1999    100            200           1500
Oregon       2000    150            100           1650
Oregon       2001    125            100           1775
```

Given this input, I would like to get to a point where I can have a list of Regions, Years and the % of completions relative to the previous years inventory

```
(Current Year Completions / Previous Year Inventory) * 100
```

The result set should look something like:

```
Region    Year    Completions
New York  1999    NaN
New York  2000    10%
New York  2001    7.58%
       .........
```

I have sorted by region and by year, but if a year is missing, it will skew the results. If a year is missing, I would expect a NaN or using the last known years value (i.e. when using 2015 completions and 2014 inventory to calculate, if 2014 is missing then NaN or use 2013 value)

```py
data = {'Region':['New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'Oregon', 'Oregon', 'Oregon'], 
        'Year':[1999,2000,2001,1999,2000,2001],
        'Completions':[100,150,125,100,150,125],
        'Incomplete':[200,100,100,200,100,100],
        'Inventory':[1500,1650,1775,1500,1650,1775]
       }

dfa = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfa = dfa.sort_values(by=['Region','Year'])
dfa['Completions'] = (dfa['Completions'] / dfa['Inventory'].shift(1) * 100)
dfa['Incomplete'] = (dfa['Incomplete'] / dfa['Inventory'].shift(1) * 100)
resultDf = dfa[['Region','Year', 'Completions', 'Incomplete']]
resultDf.head()
```

Where this falls short is that it will use the completions from Oregon in 1999 and compare it against the inventory of New York in 2001. Also if any year is ever missing, it will skew the numbers significantly.

Is there a better way to be thinking about this?

Comment: IMO the best way to handle that is to not have missing years (and for the wrap around case you can have just a dummy row).  If you have missing data I would add in rows that have `NaN` for the data you care about, that way it should be obvious when you do your YoY numbers which ones didn't have good comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following setup:

- split up the data frame by *Region* in a dictionary of data frames using `groupby`;
- on each subset, run a [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to obtain consecutive years such as 1999-2019 where missing year data receive a `NaN`;
- [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) needed year-over-year column calculations;
- at end, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all subsetted data frames in dictionary back together.

Below runs all except concatenation in a dictionary comprehension:

```
df_dict = {
           k:(d.set_index('Year')
               .reindex(range(1999,2020), axis='index')
               .reset_index()
               .assign(Region = lambda x: x['Region'].ffill(),
                       Completions_YOY = lambda x: (x['Completions'] / x['Inventory'].shift(1) * 100),
                       Incomplete_YOY = lambda x: (x['Incomplete'] / x['Inventory'].shift(1) * 100)
                       )               
              )
           for k, d in df.groupby('Region')
          }

final_df = pd.concat(df_dict, ignore_index=True)

print(final_df.head(10))
#    Year    Region  Completions  Incomplete  Inventory  Completions_YOY  Incomplete_YOY
# 0  1999  New York        100.0       200.0     1500.0              NaN             NaN
# 1  2000  New York        150.0       100.0     1650.0        10.000000        6.666667
# 2  2001  New York        125.0       100.0     1775.0         7.575758        6.060606
# 3  2002  New York          NaN         NaN        NaN              NaN             NaN
# 4  2003  New York          NaN         NaN        NaN              NaN             NaN
# 5  2004  New York          NaN         NaN        NaN              NaN             NaN
# 6  2005  New York          NaN         NaN        NaN              NaN             NaN
# 7  2006  New York          NaN         NaN        NaN              NaN             NaN
# 8  2007  New York          NaN         NaN        NaN              NaN             NaN
# 9  2008  New York          NaN         NaN        NaN              NaN             NaN
```